# Erro ao fazer deploy de aplicação no GlassFish: org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> -> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: glassfish

## Perguntas

- Por que o GlassFish 3.1.2.2 roda o ASM e esse ASM falha ao carregar as classes de minha dependência?
- Como faço para conseguir subir minha aplicação?
- Por que não acontece nos outros servidores que com GlassFish 3.1.2?

## Contexto

Estou usando o GlasshFish 3.1.2.2 (build 5) como container de aplicação no servidor do `X`, não estou conseguindo subir minha aplicação lá. Já no servidor `Y` com o GlassFish 3.1.2 (build 23)

Recentemente, subimos inserimos como dependência o *Connection Pool* do Hikari ([link para artefato do Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.7.2)). Isso implicou em subir o Java do container para Java 8.

Em um cliente que usa a nossa aplicação Web no servidor do lado deles (*aka* servidor `X`), não consegui subir a aplicação. Até a versão anterior, a versão antes do HikariCP, estava subindo tranquilamente no servidor `X`.

O erro que está dando é:

> ```
> Exception while visiting com/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/micrometer/MicrometerMetricsTracker.class of size 6582
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27392  
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)  
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  
>     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:363)  
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:171)  
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:133)  
>     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)  
>     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)  
>     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)  
>     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)  
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```

Também ocorre com outras classes do HikariCP:

- `com/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/micrometer/MicrometerMetricsTracker.class`
- `com/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/prometheus/HikariCPCollector.class`
- `com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.class`
- `com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.class`
- `com/zaxxer/hikari/util/ConcurrentBag.class`
- `com/zaxxer/hikari/util/PropertyElf.class`

Isso acaba gerando um erro na criação de um dos nossos objetos, que usa internamente classes do Hikari e herda de `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`:

> ```
> <Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [br.com.softsite.ssm.security.dataSource.SSHikariDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-jdbc-homologacao.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.softsite.ssm.security.dataSource.SSHikariDataSource
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1347)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:913)
>     ... 71 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.softsite.ssm.security.dataSource.SSHikariDataSource
>     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
>     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
>     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
>     ... 74 more
> ```

As classes usadas são:

- `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig`
- `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`

Answer (score 2):

> Isso implicou em subir o Java do container para Java 8.

Provavelmente, porque em algum lugar, o sistema usa funcionalidades do Java 8, como lambdas.

Eu diria, que a versão do ASM que está sendo usada deve ser a **3.3**. Enquanto que o suporte para Java 8 só foi introduzido na versão **5.0**.

Sugiro atualizar a dependência do ASM para a versão 5.2 ou 6.0.

> Por que o GlassFish 3.1.2.2 roda o ASM e esse ASM falha ao carregar as
>   classes de minha dependência?

Porque o HK2 faz injeção de dependência, e ele é bem abelhudo, ao ponto de usar o ASM. O ASM falha, devido a versão desatualizada, como explicado anteriormente.

> Como faço para conseguir subir minha aplicação?

Atualize o ASM, e continue fazendo o deploy como sempre fez.

> Por que não acontece nos outros servidores que com GlassFish 3.1.2?

Se eu entendi corretamente, o GlassFish 3.1.2 funciona, mas o GlassFish 3.1.2.2 não. É complicado chegar a uma conclusão definitiva nesse caso,
a diferença entre eles é mínima. Para o componente Class Model For Hk2, um usa a versão [1.1.14](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/class-model/1.1.14) e o outro a [1.1.15](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/class-model/1.1.15). A causa até pode ser uma linha no código-fonte.

No Glassfish você pode rodar a aplicação em ambiente OSGi, o que permite manter várias versões do mesmo pacote. Então nem sempre é simples dizer qual versão você está realmente usando. Isso significa que a versão de fábrica pode ser a 3.3, mas você está usando outra versão. Acredito que no seu caso,  alguém atualizou manualmente o pacote do ASM neste servidor.

A última teoria que resta, é que aquele servidor funciona corretamente porque ele não carrega o Hikari, portanto o ASM não tem a oportunidade de gerar o erro.

Comment: Vou atrás de atualizar o ASM e testar assim que eu tiver acesos à máquina. Muito consistente esse pensamento

Comment: Achamos um `jar` chamado `asm-all-repackaged`, em cujo `MANIFEST.MF` acusava ser versão 3.3, casando com o que você disse. O gerente de configurações da empresa supostamente trocou pelo que deveria ser o `5.X` mas não surtiu resultado =( Estamos tentando refazer o container do zero para ver se vai